# Design Pattern for working with IF/ELSE in Node JS / Express / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've quite a big application built, and constantly seeing this appearing across the application when working with mongoose:

```
Version.create({ version: req.body.version }, function (error, version) {
    if (error) {
        res.send(501, error)
    }
    else {
        res.send(201, version);
    }
});
```

The If/Else statement to send errors or content.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to do it with JavaScript is to return early.

```
Version.create({ version: req.body.version }, function (error, version) {
    if (error) {
        return res.send(501, error)
    }
    res.send(201, version);
});
```